# Put Font Awesome icon in top right corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I  want to put the `fa-circle` to the top corner. Basically, what I am looking for, is positioning the `fa-circle` to the top right (only for active buttons).

```css
.btn1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa.fa-circle {
  color: darkorange;
  font-size: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn1"><i class="fa fa-circle pull-right"></i>Active</button>
```

Comment: Please add float:right inline css or add  into .fa.fa-circle  and you can add margin according to that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to [Penny Liu's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61241818/13246320) fom above. but still I am unsure whether it will work in tab.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f111";
  color: darkorange;
  font-size: .35em;
  top: 0.35em;
  right: 0.25em;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn active">Active</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `btn1` to `position: relative`

And then for the icon, do

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

ie -->

```css
.btn1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.fa.fa-circle{
  color:darkorange;
  font-size: 0.25em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>


<button class="btn1"><i class="fa fa-circle pull-right"></i>Active</button>

</body>
```

Comment: It is in the button, you can play around with the margin if you want to give it a little space and adjust the position. Have added the `margin` property to my snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

To make the icon show only for the active button, you would have to hide the icon as default, then pass a class to the button to make the icon display when needed to be active with some javascript or jquery.

Code below shows and `active` class added the button, the CSS has been updated to hide the icon till the `active` class has been appended to the button.

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .btn1 {
        /*  background-color:#f5e0f9;*/
        background-color: grey;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .btn1 .fa {
        display: none;
      }
      .btn1.active .fa.fa.fa-circle {
        display: block;
      }
      .fa.fa-circle {
        color: darkorange;
        font-size: 0.25em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn1 active">
      <i class="fa fa-circle pull-right"></i>Active
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated the style and also if you remove the `active `  class the icon would not show.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you looking for:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f111";
  color: darkorange;
  font-size: .7em;
  top: 0em;
  right: 0em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn active">Active</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Not in corner, but inside button, and in between the border, little bit positioning I wanted

Comment: As per now, it's working after some change(re-sizing the circle), I want to use this styling inside on.active() js call tab - - In sidebar, active tab.Let me see that